# Are there single symbols for tree type available in QGIS?

Tags: svg, symbols, qgis

For my project I need single symbols for broadleaved and coniferous trees. Would be great if someone could help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the [Ordinance Survey's symbol set](https://github.com/OrdnanceSurvey/GeoDataViz-Toolkit/tree/master/Symbols) which has:

[Coniferous Tree](https://github.com/OrdnanceSurvey/GeoDataViz-Toolkit/blob/master/Symbols/coniferous_tree.svg) and [Non-Coniferous Tree](https://github.com/OrdnanceSurvey/GeoDataViz-Toolkit/blob/master/Symbols/non_coniferous_tree.svg) symbols

[image] [image]

There are more symbols, including for fills, in the [Master Map styles](https://github.com/OrdnanceSurvey/OSMM-Topography-Layer-stylesheets/tree/master/Schema%20version%209/Stylesheets/Geoserver%20stylesheets%20(SLD)/osmmsymbols) too.